# Image inserted into gallery not the same that is saved to storage

Tags: android, image, png, jpeg, android-gallery

I have been browsing SO for a while now but were not able to find a topic that came up with this problem.

My drawing application should be able to save the drawn images. I want to save them as PNG files, so I use this code:

```
OutputStream fOut = null;
String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(dirPath, "drawing0.png");
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
drawView.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(),
                                        file.getName(), file.getName());
```

Now the image is saved to a directory and it is a PNG file. But the gallery image itself is a JPG and it seems like the gallery is just copying the original file and transforms it into a JPG, because it tells me a different file directory:

[gallery path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW6vV.png)
[file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW6vV.png#3)

Now I want to know if this can be avoided, because if the user wants to share the picture e.g. via Dropbox it uploads the gallery JPG image and not the original PNG. I am using the standard Samsung gallery app if it matters.

Comment: Your pictures are too small and unreadable. Please tell here what the full paths are.

Comment: That is strange, I can read them pretty good.

File Path: file:///storage/emulated/0/drawing0.png
Gallery Path:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1403290099349.jpg

Comment: Ok. Why don't you store your image directly as a jpg in the Camera dir? For the rest i wonder wich actions you or the user invokes when the image should be shared. You can share any file if you want and no external activity will choose a different then i would think. Or maybe yes if it has to be resized first.

Comment: If I do store it directly in the camera directory, the gallery doesnt recognize it. However it still creates a JPG copy when I use the insertImage() method, though I am not sure if it is just the samsung gallery app that is not showing the PNG file or if this is a general thing.

Comment: If you save it yourself in the camera directory then you should not call insertImage also. But interesting that this happens. The gallery app will recognize your file when you also call the media scanner for this file. Search on this site for example code.

Comment: The media scanner did the trick, thanks to you alot. I'd mark your statement the accepted answer but that seems not possible for comments.
By the way: when I browse to the PNG's directory and open the file via the gallery, it also creates a JPG copy of it. A really weird behaviour.